# IPython installed on Mac but ipython command is not found

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, ipython, conda

I'm using MacOS and I recently installed anaconda, but it gives **ipython - command not found** when I want to check the version of ipython. It's not "a wrapper/launcher issue" which someone else in stackflow has asked about, since I could not find ipython in my directory.  I've pasted the following commands in the terminal below. I hope that helps.

```
lawn-128-61-127-169:bin s$ pwd
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin
lawn-128-61-127-169:bin s$ ls
2to3            f2py3.7         pydoc3          python3.7m
2to3-3.7        flake8          pydoc3.7        python3.7m-config
autopep8        idle3           pyflakes        pyvenv
chardetect      idle3.7         python3         pyvenv-3.7
easy_install-3.7    pip3            python3-config
f2py            pip3.7          python3.7
f2py3           pycodestyle     python3.7-config
lawn-128-61-127-169:bin s$ conda install ipython
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

lawn-128-61-127-169:bin s$ conda -V
conda 4.8.1
lawn-128-61-127-169:bin s$ python3.7 -V
Python 3.7.4
lawn-128-61-127-169:bin s$ ipython -V
-bash: ipython: command not found
lawn-128-61-127-169:bin s$ which ipython
lawn-128-61-127-169:bin s$ python3.7 -m IPython
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7: No module named IPython
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to create and activate a conda environment before you can use conda to install and use software. The [conda documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) provides a step-by-step, but basically, the following shell commands are required:

```
# create environment
conda create --name myenv

# create an environment and install the ipython package into it
conda create --name myenv ipython
```

then activate the environment:

```
conda activate myenv
```

(By default, conda stores all environments in its own `envs` directory, but provides options for specifying custom directories for storing the environment.)

If you're not sure what environments you've already created, use `conda info`:

```
conda info --envs
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! Do I need to manually activate the environment every time? Can it be activated automatically?

Comment: OP installed ipython in the `base` environment, right? In which case, can't they just `conda activate` without creating a new environment?

Comment: Yea I activated instead of creating a new one

Comment: @StellaZhu you can probably just add the command you used to activate the environemtn to your `.zshrc` (ie `echo conda activate my_env >>> ~/.zshrc`)

Comment: Explicitly creating and activating an environment will work with any version of conda, not just recent ones (from the documentation page I linked to: "Conda 4.6 added extensive initialization support so that conda works more quickly and less disruptively on a wide variety of shells... Now these shells can use the conda activate command."). It also ensures the whole concept of a conda environment doesn't get glossed over (which can cause confusion to those new to conda).